# Need formula for next letter in alphabet in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I've searched for a while but I can't find the function to get the next letter in the alphabet. Does it exist?

```
A1="A"
=char(A1+1);
expected result  "B"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this instead:

**=CHAR(CODE(A1)+1)**

[image]

This will work for capital letters *A* through *Y*.

Comment: how to do it for cols greater than Z?